# Fastest indexing of 2darray

Tags: numpy, optimization, indexing

Suppose I have an array of numbers,
where the first dimension contains 20,000 numbers from 0 up to 19999.
The second dimension contains 20 numbers, which can assume any value between 0 up to 19999.
In other words, for each index (as described by the first dimension), I have twenty alternatives in the second dimension. I call this a similarity matrix.

My goal is to replace numbers in some input stream (called "stream" below) with indices that represent similar entities using the similarity matrix. For instance, one number in the input stream may be 5. Then I look up index 5 in my similarity matrix, and sample one of the twenty alternatives for 5 which are most similar to it using the similarity matrix. The problem is I carry out this operation very frequently and it is the major bottleneck of my program.

My first attempt was this:

(where similarity_matrix is a numpy array)

```
num_samples = 20
random_numbers = [random.randint(0, similarity_matrix.shape[-1]-1) for x in range(num_samples)]
sampled_entities = similarity_matrix[stream, random_numbers]
```

which was too slow.
Then I tried

```
a = list(similarity_matrix)
interim = [a[i] for i in stream]
sampled_entities = [x[i] for x, i in zip(interim, random_numbers)]
```

which was also too slow.
Do you have alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed up your processing you can apply [`numpy.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy-random-generator-choice):

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
num_samples = 20
sampled_entities = similarity_matrix[stream, np.random.choice(similarity_matrix.shape[-1], num_samples)]
```